# Subsets of size "k" using Guava

Tags: java, set, subset, guava

I have around 1 million sets each with around 30 elements. For each set, I want to generate all subsets up to size "k" where k is going to be something like 3 or 4 or 5. I am new to Guava and decided to try it. I found the powerSet method (https://google.github.io/guava/releases/21.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Sets.html) which will generate all subsets for each of my sets.

I can loop through each power set and only take the subsets that have size less than or equal to "k". But since the power sets have size 2 ^ 30, this seems very inefficient.

I thought Guava would have a method that would allow me to generate a set of all subsets of size k but I can't find it. Am I missing something?

Comment: What do you want to do with results afterwards? Do you need `Set` interface features or is `Iterable` OK for your use case?

Comment: Iterable is ok, thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"A set of all subsets of size k" is [`Sets.combinations`](http://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Sets.html#combinations-java.util.Set-int-).

(I don't think we have a direct way to generate all subsets of size k or less, but as you point out, it's easy to build that from `combinations` -- though if you want it all in a single `Set`, as Xaerxess asks about, you'll need to build the `Set` yourself.)